# Count data types in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have `pandas.DataFrame` with too much number of columns.

I call:

```
In [2]: X.dtypes

Out[2]: VAR_0001     object
        VAR_0002      int64
                 ...   
        VAR_5000      int64
        VAR_5001      int64
```

And I can't understand what types of data I have between `VAR_0002` and `VAR_5000`

It's can be `int64`, `int8`, `float64` and so on. I see in this [blog](http://datacarpentry.github.io/python-ecology/03-data-types-and-format) native type of `pandas.DataFrame` but I think this is wrong information. How can I get this?

And other question. When I work on PC (Windows) and call this:

```
In [3]: X.dtypes[X.dtypes.map(lambda x: x=='bool')]
```

I get several columns with this type of data. But when I use this command on Mac, I get nothing. WAT?

Comment: You're going to have to post sample data and code to reproduce this anomaly, also post your python, numpy and pandas version for both os'es

Comment: I think, that's not neccesary. I'm sure, that my mistake in some manipulation

Comment: Err, I'm with @EdChum on the second question. You have a difference between a mac and a pc, and *presumably* the same code. Need to see beyond the specific code to help. or not...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To answer your first question do the following:

```
df.dtypes.value_counts()
```

Example:

```
In [4]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0], 'b':['asds'], 'c':[0]})
df.dtypes
Out[4]:
a     int64
b    object
c     int64
dtype: object
In [5]:

df.dtypes.value_counts()
Out[5]:
int64     2
object    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you also format this output? Can I get fe. an output like `The number of int64 objects is: 2`?

Comment: You'd have to iterate row wise and format the string output

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: `count = df.dtypes.value_counts()
for i in count.index:
    print('The number of ', i, 'objects is ', count[i])`

Comment: How could you modify this for just one column of the dataframe? Like if I have a column with multiple dtypes in it and want a count for each, how many are ints, how many are floats, etc. If I try `count = df['COLUMN'].dtypes.value_counts() for i in count.index: print('The number of ', i, 'objects is ', count[i])`, I get an error saying that numpy.dtype object is not iterable. Thanks

Comment: @Korzak that is tricky, your issue is that your column is now mixed dtypes so you lose any vectorisation operations. You could transpose it, convert to a df and then call the above so `df['COLUMN'].to_frame().T.dtypes.value_counts()` should work, this is untested

Comment: @lte__:   len(df.select_dtypes(include='int64').keys())